# Can higher quality prints be achieved by switching filiment type between printing 1" high detail miniatures and larger low detail vehicle

Tags: filament-choice

When 3D printing model for tabletop gaming system, should the same filament type be used for to print 1" gaming pieces with curved surfaces and lots of small detail, and vehicles which are much larger but which have lots of flat surface and sharp angles?

For example, could an overall higher quality print be achieved using a specific filament types to print a custom Warhammer 40K space marine, and a different one for a Warhammer 40K rhino assault vehicle?

Replace Warhammer 40K with any comparable sized gaming system as required.

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is quality, the filament type (PLA vs ABS vs PETG vs etc.) is not as important as the slicing parameters. In filament style printers, one compensates surface quality for speed of printing.

A feature of a number of slicing programs allows one to change layer height at varying vertical locations in a model/full bed of models.

For example, a model with a number of vertical flat surfaces will benefit from faster printing if the layer height is set to 0.300 mm on a machine with a 0.40 mm nozzle. A model with organic shapes and few flat surfaces, especially those with curvature in the z-axis would benefit from a higher quality appearance when printed with 0.100 layer height.

Consider that a model may have a pedestal type of base, creating the option for a 0.300 mm layer, but as the model prints, the legs (also mostly vertical) will not be degraded overmuch by such a setting, but once reaching curved areas including the chest, shoulders, arm muscles, one would desire higher quality 0.100 mm layers.

The slicing software permits one to designate the first section to one layer height, then switch operations to the thinner height. There are usually no limits to the number of changes permitted in a model print, other than the operator's patience and tolerance for such quantities.